# react-native-apple-authentication not returning email neither fullname

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement Apple SignIn in my ReactNative app, I added the react-native-apple-authentication (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-apple-authentication) and then installed the pods, then I added to the Apple SignIn capability in Xcode.

After pressing the button and trying to log in with my Apple account, the following object is returned:

```
{
  authorizationCode: null
  authorizedScopes: Array(0)
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array(0)
  email: null
  fullName: null
  identityToken: null
  realUserStatus: 1
  state: null
  user: "receivedMyTokenHere"
}
```

But I need the fullName and email, don't know how to get them.
Inside the library, the method AppleAuthentication.requestAsync is requiring the fullName and email scopes, but for some reason I'm not receiving them. Any idea?